# SQL - How can you use WHERE instead of LEFT/RIGHT JOIN?

Tags: sql

since I am a bit rusty, I was practicing SQL on [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) and was trying to replace the LEFT JOIN completly with WHERE. How can i do this so it does the same thing as the premade function in the website?

What I tried so far is:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers, Orders
WHERE Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID OR Customers.CustomerID != Orders.CustomerID
Order by Customers.CustomerName;
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: First why would you do that thats old ANSI fashion when almost all dbms now support new join with on statements. Secondly, what you want to acheive through this and lastly how?

Comment: @mureinik I normally use MySQL but on this example the one on the website. Not sure what they are using.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja Just out of my own curiosity :)

Comment: You're going the wrong direction. The `JOIN` + `ON` syntax is good, comma separated tables has been obsolete for 25 years now. If this is practice, _don't practice the bad thing!_ Practice doing it the better way.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yeah was just practice to get into proggramming again but i see using WHERE in this particular issue is kinda pointless, was just trying to remeber the differences between them again. Ty for the warning :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to replace

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
```

with

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers, Orders
WHERE ???
```

this is doomed to failure. Consider Customers has two rows and Orders has zero. The outer join will return two rows.

The cross join (`FROM Customers, Orders`) will return zero rows.

In standard SQL a `WHERE` clause can only reduce the rows from that - not increase them so there is nothing you can put for `???` that will give your desired results.

Before ANSI-92 joins were introduced some systems used to have proprietary operators for this, such as `*=` in SQL Server but [this was removed from the product](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/outer-join-operators-and-are-not-supported-in-90-or-later-compatibility-modes?view=sql-server-2014).

Comment: Indeed, i see that now as well. Tyvm

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you.

```
SELECT 
   c.CustomerName, 
   o.OrderID
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Orders o 
on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID 
Order by c.CustomerName;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I wanted to eliminate left join ^^

Comment: @M. Anderson LEFT JOIN is always best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to replace this:

```
SELECT c.CustomerName, o.OrderID
FROM Customers c LEFT JOIN
     Orders o
     ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
ORDER BY c.CustomerName;
```

Then you can use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT c.CustomerName, o.OrderID
FROM Customers c JOIN
     Orders o
     ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
UNION ALL
SELECT c.CustomerName, o.OrderID
FROM Customers c 
WHERE NOT EXIST (SELECT 1 FROM Orders o WHERE c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID)
ORDER BY CustomerName
```

However, the `LEFT JOIN` is really a much better way to go.

Comment: Thank your for answering, let me play around with that 1 sec

Comment: @M.Anderson . . . This seems to answer your question.

Comment: Not really - they were specifically trying to replace the outer join with cross join + where - not by extending the query with union all. So the answer - "that ain't gonna work because ..." seems more appropriate